# APNS Certificate Issue while sending notification to iOS App

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

To send notifications to my adhoc app i selected previously Distribution APNS service. I got notifications successfully.

But now while creating certificate I’m in confusion which one to select in portal..

[image] 
  [image]

Selected (sandbox&Prodcution) and created .p12 file and uploaded to my sever..
But Im getting following error
You have selected the Production server, yet your Certificate does not appear to be the Production certificate! Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!

I figured out the Issue is due to PushSharp,

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/585#issue

But unable to edit/Modify that code in that class.

Please help me

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

For Development Notification:
Select - "Apple Push Notification service SSL(SandBox)"

For Production/Distribution Notification:
Select - "Apple Push Notification service SSL(SandBox & Production)"

Comment: I observed one more difference, for my previous apps it says "Apns production", but for new app id it says "Apple push services"  in portal . Please check link https://www.dropbox.com/s/1w5ruckfwbkhcaf/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-21%20at%2012.45.10%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: May I know your server? Is it php or .net?

Comment: Yeah No problem,  its .net

Comment: I wondered by seeing the portal in production mode Why again sandbox .. Previously I used to think sandbox means Development otherwise its production

Comment: export .p12 file with private key.

Comment: @sivakrishna do you get the result? I have caught this issue, too. and I use php shell to send notification, it shows ok, but my device can not receive the notification.

Comment: No, My service team is using pushsharp to send notifications.                         https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/585#issue  but the problem is they are unable to edit the code in that class

Answer (score 0):

After Changing to following code in my server side

pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(true, appleCertificate, password));

to

pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(true, appleCertificate, password, true));

Changes: Added One more parameter to constructor to disable certificate check.

Now Im getting notifications for old/new certificates..

Thanks..