# iOS push notification certification issue: sandbox & distribution combined

Tags: ios, notifications, push

Please see the screenshot: 
[image]

[image]

no longer can create single distribution ssl certification, and generate the certification for this type, double-click it into keychain, the name is "Apple Push Service:..." not "Apple Production IOS Push Service:...", and I generate the certification to pem,and run the php script to push a notification to my device, the script result show connect to APNs successfully and message delivered, but device not receive the notification. it's the issue of the new kind certification? because the php script file is used before and every time it is ok except this time. Also I test to use previous distribution certification to push, and it works fine.

So how is it? Any advice is appreciate!

the same questions are:
[APNS Certificate Issue while sending notification to iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390486/apns-certificate-issue-while-sending-notification-to-ios-app/34390552#34390552)

[Apple Push Services created instead of Apple Production iOS Push Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431337/apple-push-services-created-instead-of-apple-production-ios-push-services/34431678#34431678)

but both above not fix my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your app on device is build with correct provisioning profile.

Comment: @Muneeba I have used the Ad Hoc Provisioning profile. it made me confused. Any advice?

Comment: Adhoc Provisioning profile containing your app's bundle id?? Or is it a wild card Provisioning? If its  the one with your app bundle id,you are getting the device toke properly also  make sure you have enable push notification that bundle id plush use the production gate in your php code.

Comment: @Muneeba Yea,the provision profile contain the app's bundle id, and get the correct device token, and the url use for distribution push in the php is "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195", this should be correct. so any other advice? Thanks!

Comment: @Muneeba  and when i run the php script, it show "connected" and message is delivered. but device didn't get notification.

Comment: And push notification is not a silent one right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99375/discussion-between-muneeba-and-blues-zhou).